# Ajax.AjaxMethod calling a non-AjaxMethod?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Is it possible to call a method that is **not** tagged with `[Ajax.AjaxMethod]` from an AjaxMethod?  Basically I have a method that populates a GridView control which is itself inside an UpdatePanel; it loads some data, sets some properties, etc.  However, I need to also call this method from an AjaxMethod that will pass the same information to it that a non-Ajax method does.  The problem currently is the GridView control is null when the AjaxMethod tries to call methods on it, resulting in a NullReferenceException.

How can I fix this so the Ajax method can access controls on the page?  I don't think I can simply re-instantiate the control at runtime.  Should I be running the Ajax code inside of an UpdatePanel or something like that, instead of making the call directly via JavaScript?  I need to do some client-side processing as a callback as well, so that's why I was calling the AjaxMethod direct from JavaScript, but I cannot access the controls on the page which are filled by the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use Jquery's AJAX method?

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: <URL of your method>,
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Will I be able to perform operations on server-side controls on the page with that?  For some reason I always thought I couldn't do it that way either.  I'll have to try it; it would make it a lot easier since I'm using jQuery for everything else on the page except the AjaxMethods and UpdatePanels.

Comment: What are some server side controls you are using? Embedded server controls that render textboxes, etc.? You can update them via an AJAX call by accessing them via their ID, or if they are databinded somehow, update them on the server via your AJAX call.

Comment: Basically the ajax method is passing a DataSet and a string to a method that sets properties of a GridView which is inside an UpdatePanel; currently the data is there but the GridView control is null.

Comment: You can serialize a DataSet in Javascript and then pass it with JQuery using AJAX. http://forums.asp.net/t/1284311.aspx -- read that link, it will show you how. Then passing a string is easy, you would just create a Json object to pass via AJAX, and the other param besides the serialized dataset (which would become a list, and converted back on the server), would just be a string